# How to marshal C# type to LPWSTR *

Tags: c#, c++, com, marshalling, comobject

I have a native C++ project which has a struct that looks like this:

```
  struct COMStringArray
    {
        long lSize;
        LPWSTR * array;
    };
```

Which uses a com object written in C#, so I need to marshal my C# types to be used in my C++ project.
I tried this:

```
public struct COMStringArray
{
    public int lSize;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
    public string[] array;
}
```

But I have the following error when registering with REGASM the dll:
"Warning Arrays in structs must be SafeArrays or ByValArrays".

Is it possible to output something like LPWSTR *? Do I need to use IntPtr?

Comment: @HansPassant also, if you would know the issue with registering LPArray in a struct, you would have understood the question.

Comment: @berthos by that logic, you could also just post code with no text and hope people to decipher it for you. Including error messages helps make your question searchable, and welcomes more focused answers. The more precise your question is, the better the answers you'll get.